# Converting ECDSA signature from DER to RS format in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, jwt

I am using AWS Key Management Service to store a private key. This private key I want to use in my .Net program to generate the signature for a JWT.

Calling KMS with and getting a signature back is easy but the returned signature is in 'DER' format and JWT requires 'RS' format. So I need to make this conversion somehow.

I was expecting it to be easy to call a .Net API to make the conversion from one signature format to another. So far all my googling has not turned up any helpful information about .Net APIs and co-pilot also did not provide any information that was actually useful/correct.

So I am looking for any pointer to a .Net APIs for making the conversion or Nuget package with that capability.

Comment: Where did you get this private key from?

Comment: The private key was generated within KMS. By design there is no way that my program can get hold of the private key from KMS but the program can call KMS and perform cryptographics operations on it. This includes generating a digital signature with the pricate key.